# Java won't accept decimal number for Double variable

Tags: java, double

I have these very simple 3 lines of code which, to my understanding, should allow the user to enter a decimal number and then spit the number out.

```
  System.out.print("Enter a number.\n"); 
  double number = input.nextDouble();
  System.out.println(number);
```

When I do however enter a decimal number Java throw an InputMismatchException; although when I enter en integer the number it spits out show a decimal place. This is so simple I couldn't even google it, and yet I'm completely lost.

EDIT Wait what? I just tried and it actually accepts "2,4" but not "2.4". Can that be changed?

Comment: Do you use a thousand separator? what character do you use for decimals? You might need to change the locale.

Comment: Try `1.0` and `1,0` ....

Comment: googling gave me this link..please check if this is what you want.. http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/106933/reading-from-console-input#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the locale (I assume you are using a Scanner):

```
scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: Java uses your OS settings by default unless you specify a different setting. You can do that at your application level with `Locale.setDefault(...)` or you can do it locally like in my answer. To change the OS setting, on Windows, I think it would be in the Regional Settings.

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing what your 'input' element is, I can only speculate that you might have a locale issue here? E.g. entering '2,4' instead of '2.4'?